# Ckeditor Tags to be used for generating a textbox property

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

My question is how to create a box on extreme side of the page in ckeditor
This is the code what is used but unable to generate the same in word.

```
<table border="4" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="height:5in; margin-left:5in; margin-right:5in; margin-top:-0.7in; width:100px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternately,i used div property but i couldn't get what i wanted

```
<div style="border-bottom: #000 1px solid; text-align: center; border-left: #000 1px solid; height: 36px; margin-left: 50px; border-top: #000 1px solid; margin-right: 50px; border-right: #000 1px solid">AGREEMENT FOR HYPOTHECATION-AGRICULTURAL ADVANCES</div>
```

Can anyone help me out like what is the exact thing to be done to position a box on left side of page and simultaneously  can alter the text box size?
Thanks in Advance